# Scraping flash websites

Tags: flash, screen-scraping

I am willing to create a script that takes information from a website which is done in flash.

I was about to start coding an application doing something like:

- moving mouse to position x,y.
- do a mouse click.
- wait x msec.
- get data.

My question is: Is there a better way to do this? Any lib?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: What language are you going to be coding in?

Comment: Language is not a problem as long as it works on linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Selenium.

Answer (score 2):

there isn't a simple solution for flash web sites. selenium or watin or any other tools can't access to the flash unless you've got access the source codes of flash.

you can use one of these components with image recognation library, which can do possible to click on flash buttons.