# xmlHttpRequest to a flash Website

Tags: javascript, flash

I am using javascript to do XMLHTTP Requests (GET) calls, and I want to get the content of the Flash website, but when I do xmlhttpRequest to that website  I get flash error saying:
"This content requires the Adobe Flash Player."

can some one help me in this, I really do not have any more information about it to share :(   , just a simple XMLHTTP REQUEST.

(and its not about CORS, I have already fixed that)

Comment: Your browser might be blocking flash altogether.

Comment: are you getting a html page with flash embded, or trying to get the flash content (the .swf file) directly?

Comment: @Schlaus its not browser.. its xmlhttp request which is not returning the correct response

Comment: @JaromandaX  yea I am trying to get content of the website, its Login page. so may be HTML containing Flash

Comment: This is probably relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985474/scraping-flash-websites?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get flash error saying: "This content requires the Adobe Flash
>   Player."

That's not a Flash error. Check the source code of the html, I bet that "error" is just text written as alternative / placeholder text when Flash embed is not displaying (ie: not covering the same text).

**Why can't you scrape this Flash content with XMLHTTP request?**...
Flash files are actually **compiled applications**, not a text document like some .JS or .HTML files. You have to run the application within its required operating system (in this case, the installed FlashPlayer plugin). Until then you have no "content" to scrape.

**What can you do?**...
Depends what you want to scrape. For example with some Flash-based Weather App, the daily updates must be coming from somewhere like a JSON or XML file so really, to get today's weather details you simply check the JSON file *(input)* not scrape the SWF *(output)*. 
Apply this logic together with your browser's *Developer Tools* to see what other files are listed after SWF load. Maybe they actually hold the data you need...?

If the content is hard-coded into the Flash file then you'll have to go into the [**bytes of `SWF`**](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf-file-format-spec.pdf) to extract it (no longer about XMLHTTP requests). Here's a blog [**article**](http://www.mlsite.net/blog/?p=27) from some who wanted to extract images from swf, maybe it can help you with hints.

Comment: Thanks for your help @VC.One   :)